# Why the following variations of s/g from command line are wrong?

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

I have a small file as follows:

```
$ cat text.txt
vacation
cat
This is a test
```

This command substitutes all occurrences of cat to CAT correctly as I wanted:

```
$ perl -p -i -e '
s/cat/CAT/g;
' text.txt
```

But why the following two mess the file up?
The following deletes the contents of the file

```
$ perl -n -i -e '  
$var = $_;  
$var =~ s/cat/CAT/g;  
' text.txt
```

And this one just does not do the substitution correctly

```
$ perl -p -i -e '
$var = $_;
$var =~ s/cat/CAT/g;
' text.txt

$ cat text.txt
cation
cat
This is a test
```

Why? What am I messing up here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911424/how-to-view-the-code-block-genereated-by-n-or-p-switch-in-perl-one-liner or check `perl -h`

Answer (score 4):

`-p` prints out each line automatically (the contents of `$_`, which contains the current line's contents), which re-populates the file (due to the `-i` flag in use), where `-n` loops over the file like `-p` does, but it doesn't automatically print. You have to do that yourself, otherwise it just overwrites the file with nothing. The `-n` flag allows you to skip over lines that you don't want to re-insert into the original file (amongst other things), whereby with `-p`, you'd have to use conditional statements along with `next()` etc. to achieve the same result.

```
perl -n -i -e '  
$var = $_;  
$var =~ s/cat/CAT/g;
print $var;  
' text.txt
```

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

In your last example, `-p` will only automatically print `$_` (the original, unmodified line). It doesn't auto-print `$var` at all, so in that case, you'd have to print `$var` like in the example above, but then you'd get both the original line, and the modified one printed to the file.

You're better off not assigning `$_` to anything if all you're doing is overwriting a file. Just use it as is. eg. (same as your first example):

```
perl -p -i -e '   
s/cat/CAT/g;  
' text.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean "re-populates the file"? It prints in STDOUT right?

Comment: No, not with `-i`. That flag says rewrite the file, `test.txt` in-place. So you're writing back to that file with the `-i` flag.

Comment: to print to `STDOUT`, don't use `-i`